# json_encode em tag html

Tags: php, json

Como faco para colocar um json gerado pelo php em uma tag de um link

```
$array = array('a','b','c');

$json = json_encode($array);

$link = '<a href.. tag="'.$json.'">';
```

// tentei com JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG  e não funciona

Comment: sim, soque ele quebra com aspas duplas geradas pelo json_encode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma que pretendes, deverás fazer uso da função [`htmlentities()`](https://php.net/htmlentities) de forma a que as aspas duplas sejam convertidas para a sua entidade HTML:

```
$array = array('a','b','c');

$json = json_encode($array);

$link = '<a href.. tag="'.htmlentities($json).'">';
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/9Pzx8W).